# ORA 00937 while using INSERT INTO SELECT

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g

When I am running the below insert into select statement, I get `ORA 00937` because the below query cannot deal with one of the sub selects on `APPLICATIONS` table. I don't want to hardcode that value. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

```
insert into CONFIGURATION_PARAMETER_VALUES
( ID
, NAME
, DESCRIPTION
, DATA_TYPE
, VALUE_STRING
, VALUE_INTEGER
, VALUE_DATE
, VALUE_FLOAT
, VALUE_TIMESTAMP
, APPLICATION_ID
, DELETED
) 
select NVL(MAX(ID),0)+1
       , 'Alert_Statuses_AllExceptNoStatus'
       , 'Suspicious'
       , 'String'
       , 'RBS_EIM_AL_008'
       , null
       , null
       , null
       , null
       , (select ID from APPLICATIONS where name = 'Rabobank v 1.0.0.0')
       , 'N'
  from CONFIGURATION_PARAMETER_VALUES
```

Comment: There is a possibility that your sub-query returns more than one value. So, try your sub-query like this

select MAX(ID) from APPLICATIONS where name = 'Rabobank v 1.0.0.0'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's not too late, I'd suggest implementing a `SEQUENCE` instead of counting. You may not get strict numeric order (there can be gaps), but you'll get a unique value every time:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE Config_Parm_Values_Seq START WITH <1 + your current max ID>;
```

Also note that your `INSERT` as it stands right now will behave as follows:

- If there are no records in the table, it will insert nothing.
- If there are records in the table, it will double the number of rows in your table every time you execute it.

So, even if you don't use the sequence, I'd consider a "plain old" `INSERT` instead of an `INSERT ... SELECT`. This example uses the sequence:

```
insert into CONFIGURATION_PARAMETER_VALUES
( ID
, NAME
, DESCRIPTION
, DATA_TYPE
, VALUE_STRING
, VALUE_INTEGER
, VALUE_DATE
, VALUE_FLOAT
, VALUE_TIMESTAMP
, APPLICATION_ID
, DELETED
) VALUES (
       Config_Parm_Values_Seq.NEXTVAL -- Use seqname.nextval to get
                                      -- the next value from the sequence
       , 'Alert_Statuses_AllExceptNoStatus'
       , 'Suspicious'
       , 'String'
       , 'RBS_EIM_AL_008'
       , null
       , null
       , null
       , null
       , (select MAX(ID) from APPLICATIONS where name = 'Rabobank v 1.0.0.0')
       , 'N')
```

Comment: This is also a useful solution. The only thing I am doubtful is about the use of the sequence. It is ideal to use a sequence. But, after populating the table, I don't know how this will work. Even when the user does a `SELECT MAX(ID)+1 FROM...", the query returns an error.

Comment: Thanks @Rachcha - I agree with your assessment that the sequence is ideal though it might not be a good fit here. I'm sure the `SELECT MAX(ID)+1...` can be debugged and gotten to work, probably with an `NVL` or some other fallback. Then again, if more than one user tries to run the non-sequence `INSERT` at the same time, will that cause a duplicate ID? I've always used sequences so I don't really know what will happen.

Comment: @Rachcha - thanks for the catch on the `NEXTVAL`. Rookie mistake on my part; I think I need another cup of coffee :)  I tried to accept your change but couldn't figure out how, so I just typed it in manually. Again, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `SELECT` statement where you are using `SELECT NVL(MAX(ID), 0) + 1`.
As you are using `MAX` function in the `SELECT` list, you must use a `GROUP BY`, which is not the solution here.

Use something like the following:

```
insert into CONFIGURATION_PARAMETER_VALUES
( ID
, NAME
, DESCRIPTION
, DATA_TYPE
, VALUE_STRING
, VALUE_INTEGER
, VALUE_DATE
, VALUE_FLOAT
, VALUE_TIMESTAMP
, APPLICATION_ID
, DELETED
) 
select (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM configuration_parameter_values) + 1
        -- above line instead of NVL(MAX(ID),0)+1
        -- You can also put NVL function around the subquery.
       , 'Alert_Statuses_AllExceptNoStatus'
       , 'Suspicious'
       , 'String'
       , 'RBS_EIM_AL_008'
       , null
       , null
       , null
       , null
       , (select ID from APPLICATIONS where name = 'Rabobank v 1.0.0.0')
       -- Warning: The above subquery can generate a TOO_MANY_ROWS exception.
       -- Use the solution in the other answer to avoid this.
       , 'N'
  from CONFIGURATION_PARAMETER_VALUES
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply but your query is giving  ORA-00001: unique constraint (CFG_PARAM_VAL_PK) violated

Comment: Is that on the `CONFIGURATION_PARAMETER_VALUES.ID` column?

Comment: Or perhaps you can try `SELECT NVL((SELECT MAX(ID)+1 FROM configuration_parameter_values), 1)`

Comment: @user2263807 - try running just the `SELECT` part of your query (without the `INSERT`) so you can see what your `INSERT` is trying to add.